# Simple Injector - Creating Module

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I want to change my DI library autofac to simple injector.

I have a module in my business layer which is keeping registration for data access and business layer registrations. And I register this module from API. How can I do this with simple injector?

Simple code below.

In business layer.

```
public class AutofacModules : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

In WebAPI.

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModules());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found in the documentation:

- [How to package registrations](https://simpleinjector.org/howto#package-registrations)
- [Batch / Automatic registration](https://simpleinjector.org/advanced#batch-automatic-registration)
- [ASP.NET Web API Integration Guide](https://simpleinjector.org/webapi)

Long story short, change your code to the following:

```
// Your module
public static class BusinessLayerBootstrapper 
{
    public static void Bootstrap(Container container)
    {
        var registrations =
            from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            where type.Name.EndsWith("Service")
            from service in type.GetInterfaces()
            select new { service, type };

        foreach (var reg in registrations) {
            container.Register(reg.service, reg.type, Lifestyle.Scoped);
    }
}
```

In WebAPI.

```
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

BusinessLayerBootstrapper.Bootstrap(container);
```

Comment: Thank you. I looked the documentation but I missed seeing the add new dll (.packaging)

Comment: Don't use the Packaging dll. You don't need it. Use the method presented here.